# Omitting "to be" verb in correlative comparative in formal writing

Tags: correlative-constructions

Can we omit "to be" verb in correlative comparative in formal writing?

I can say in spoken English it is completely correct to do so, but can we write the following sentence in a formal writing:

> 1 The brighter the sun, the happier I feel.

or the only acceptable form is:

> 2 The brighter the sun **is**, the happier I feel.

Comment: Yes, omit the verb. It simply gets in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean by "formal writing" is a bit unclear. Do you mean texts that are published by major publishing houses? Legal documents? Epistles to royalty?

Including "to be" does make the sentence sound a bit more "formal" (at least to my ears), but it is often omitted in writing. In fact, you can sometimes even omit more than that. For example, if you [search Google Books for "the bigger the better"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20bigger%20the%20better%22&biw=1536&bih=751&tbm=bks&oq=%22the%20bigger%20the%20better), you will find that phrase used in all sorts of documents: works of fiction, scientific reports, records of U.S. Congressional hearings, academic conference proceedings, etc.